# Recommendation for an in-memory database

Tags: database, nosql, rdbms, in-memory-database

I would like to remove sql dependency of small chunks of data that I load on (almost) each request on a web application. Most of the data is key-value/document structured, but a relational solution is not excluded. The data is not too big so I want to keep it in memory for higher availability.

What solution would you recommend?

Comment: Can you share what web stack you are using? LAMP or .NET or ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest and most widely used in-memory Key-value storage is [MemcacheD](http://memcached.org/). The introduction page re-iterates what you are asking for:

> Memcached is an in-memory key-value store for small chunks of arbitrary data (strings, objects) from results of database calls, API calls, or page rendering.

The client list is impressive. It's been for a long time. Good documentation. It has API for almost every programming language. Horizontal scaling is pretty simple. As my experience goes Memcached is good.

You may also want to look into [MemBase](http://www.membase.org/).

Answer (score 6):

[Redis](http://redis.io/) is perfect for this kind of data. It also supports some fundamental datastructures and provides operations on them.

I recently converted my Django forum app to use it for all real-time/tracking data - it's so good to no longer have the icky feeling you get when you do this kind of stuff (`SET views = views + 1` and other writes on every page view) with a relational database.

Here's an example of using Redis to store data required for user activity tracking, including keeping an ordered set of last seen users up to date, in Python:

```
def seen_user(user, doing, item=None):
    """
    Stores what a User was doing when they were last seen and updates
    their last seen time in the active users sorted set.
    """
    last_seen = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()))
    redis.zadd(ACTIVE_USERS, user.pk, last_seen)
    redis.setnx(USER_USERNAME % user.pk, user.username)
    redis.set(USER_LAST_SEEN % user.pk, last_seen)
    if item:
        doing = '%s <a href="%s">%s</a>' % (
            doing, item.get_absolute_url(), escape(str(item)))
    redis.set(USER_DOING % user.pk, doing)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the sql but want to keep the db in memory, you might want to check out sqlite (see http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

If you don't want the sql and you really only have key-value pairs, why not just store them in a map / hash / associative array and be done with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you end up needing an in-memory database, [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is a very good option.

Answer (score 2):

One more database to consider: [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gYaDfo). Berkeley DB allows you to configure the database to be in-memory, on-disk or both. It supports both a key-value (NoSQL) and a SQL API. Berkeley DB is often used in combination with web applications because it's embedded, easily deployed (it deploys with your application), highly configurable and very reliable. There are several e-Retail web sites that rely on Berkeley DB for their e-Commerce applications, including Amazon.com.

Comment: You should disclose your relationship with BDB in this answer.

Comment: Another problem with BerkeleyDB is it's AGPL license, meaning if you want to use it in your application, you must either purchase a proprietary license or open source your app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but you should look into a caching framework (something that may be included in the tools you are using now). With a repository pattern you ask for the data, there you check if you have it in cache by key. I you don't, you fetch it from the database, if you do, you fetch it from the cache.

It will depend on what kind of data you are handling so it's up to you to decide how long to keep data in cache. Perhaps a sliding timeout is best as you'll keep the data as long as the  key keeps being request. Which means if the cache has data for a user, once the user goes away, the data will expire from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Can you shard this data? Is data access pattern simple and stable (does not change with changing business requirements)? How critical is this data (session context, for example, is not too hard to restore, whereas some preferences a user has entered on a settings page should not be lost)?

Typically, provided you can shard and your data access patterns are simple and do not mutate too much, you choose Redis. If you look for something more reliable and supporting more advanced data access patterns, Tarantool is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check out this :

http://www.mongodb.org/

Its a really good No-SQL database with drivers and support for all major languages.